# EJB Ambiguous dependencies: How to specify which class to Inject

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb, cdi

I am trying to inject an object in my EJB like this:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/auth")
public class Login {

@Inject
UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials;
```

The problem is the UsernamePasswordCredentials has a child class and both classes have the same qualifiers which causes an  ambiguous dependencies. How do I specify that I want to inject an instance of the parent class and not the child class? Error message looks like this:

> Ambiguous dependencies for type UsernamePasswordCredentials with qualifiers @Default
>
> Managed Bean [class org.picketlink.idm.credential.UsernamePasswordCredentials] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
>
> Managed Bean [class org.picketlink.idm.credential.TOTPCredentials] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the programmatic lookup mechanism to restrict the actual type of the needed bean:

```
@Inject
Instance<UsernamePasswordCredentials> credInst;

public UserNamePasswordCredentials getCredentials() {
  return credInst.select(UsernamePasswordCredentials.class).get();
}
```

Beyond that, I'm not a Picket Link expert, but I think you are doing something wrong with the framework. Picket Link CDI integration was very well crafted so I'm a bit puzzled you could encounter such an issue in a standard usage.

Comment: I think you should ask on the picketlink user forum https://developer.jboss.org/en/picketlink/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~objecttype~objecttype[thread]

Comment: If I had to guess, you're not meant to inject these classes.  There's no beans.xml in the JAR that they come from.  These classes are not from the CDI integration.  Since they're both dependent injecting them isn't going to help you - you probably need a custom producer.